# How to Create Sublime-Like Build Systems in Vim?

Tags: neovim

I am currently new to neovim and still adjusting to all of the keybindings but something that has me a bit stuck is being able to easily run my code. The text editor I used before trying out vim was Sublime Text 3 and in that text editor, all I had to do was press cmd + B and it would use a build system that either came with the text editor or one that I made myself. I haven't found a way to do this within vim and the closet I have gotten to doing something similar to this is by adding this to my init.vim "command PYrun :!python3 %" but I have only gotten this to work with python and it is no where near as good as the build systems in Sublime. Is there some way that neovim can read the file's extension (eg., .py, .asm, .cs) and use a preconfigured build system to run the code?

Default Python Build System:

```
"cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"quiet": true
```

My Customized Assembly Build System:

```
"shell": true,
"cmd": ["nasm -f macho64 ${file} && ld -macosx_version_min 10.12 -lSystem -o ${file_base_name} ${file_base_name}.o && ./${file_base_name}"],
"file_regex": "^(.+):([0-9]+)()?: error: (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.assembly"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit research, I found a plugin called "[quickrun.vim](https://github.com/D0n9X1n/quickrun.vim)*" and this plugin (from what I understand) runs a series of commands based on the extension of the current file you are working on. You can use the default "build-systems" that the plugin comes with, however, you create your own build systems by specifying what commands need to be run when ever you use QuickRun on a specific file type. Down below are my current settings and build systems for quickrun.vim.

My C++ Build System:

```
let g:quickrun_known_file_types = {
    \"cpp": ["!g++ % -o $(basename % .cpp) && eval ./$(basename % .cpp)"],
\}
```

My Assembly Build System in my init.vim:

```
let g:quickrun_known_file_types = {
    \"asm": ["!nasm -f macho64 % && ld -macosx_version_min 10.12 -lSystem -o $(basename % .asm) $(echo $(basename % .asm).o) && eval ./$(basename % .asm)"]
\}
```

My Current Quickrun Settings:

```
let g:quickrun_known_file_types = {
    \"cpp": ["!g++ % -o $(basename % .cpp) && eval ./$(basename % .cpp)"],
    \"c": ["!gcc % -o $(basename % .c)"],
    \"vim": ["source %"],
    \"py": ["!python3 %"],
    \"asm": ["!nasm -f macho64 % && ld -macosx_version_min 10.12 -lSystem -o $(basename % .asm) $(echo $(basename % .asm).o) && eval ./$(basename % .asm)"]
\}

nnoremap <space>b :QuickRun<CR>
```

Once you have the plugin installed and you have your quickrun.vim settings in your .vimrc/init.vim, you can just execute "QuickRun" in command mode and the plugin will then do the rest of the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run a file quickly without any preparations, I'd recommend [quickrun.vim](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-quickrun). It has some preconfigured run-configurations so you just need to run `:Quickrun` to execute your current file and you can also customize it according to your needs.

If you want to have different running options (if it's that what you mean), than you could use the builtin `:make` command or this plugin: [asynctasks.vim](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/asynctasks). This plugin gives you the ability to create "profiles" to switch between different execution "styles".

I've only tried `QuickRun` yet, so here's a little demonstration how it looks like (opened a `bash` file and `python` file):

[image: Demo with python and bash]

You could also give [asyncrun](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/asyncrun) a try, which runs your executions (as the name says) asynchrony.

Comment: Have you created your own run-configurations with QuickRun and if you have, could you provide information as to how you did so?

Comment: Well I use QuickRun if I don't need some specifique run-configurations. In general I have this mapping: `noremap <localleader>lr :QuickRun -outputter loclist -hook/time/enable 1 -input "="` but if you want to use extra run-configurations I'd recommend `async` or `asynctasks` as I've said in my answer. (I'm using Async mostly)

Comment: did it help you?

Comment: It both helped and also didn't help. The quickrun plugin you mentioned in your answer did not suite my needs, however, I did find another plugin that allowed me to create my own "build systems" called "quickrun.vim." I'll answer my question and explain what I did to get Sublime-Like Build Systems in vim.